# Usage of "Pet" in "Pet Peeve"

Tags: phrase-usage

Why would someone want a **peeve** as a **pet**?

Upon searching for **pet peeve**, one explanation for the usage of **pet** was

> the complaint is adopted like a pet

This meaning I can understand in

> **pet** project

where one takes it **under one's wing** and **cares** for it.  If I were to adopt a **pet** this is what I would do. **Pets** are usually warm and fuzzy, and certainly **likeable**. **Peeves** less so.

Except for possibly **alliteration**, why is a **peeve**, that I must always feel the need to complain about (another searched definition), a **pet**?

Comment: Somewhat related: [hobbyhorse](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hobbyhorse).

Comment: You know what really grinds my gears?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Welcome to English, where, on a long enough timeline, all things become their opposite. Case in point, the word *epic*, which now describes trivial things, like finding your favorite soda in a random corner store...

*Pet* is a synonym for *favorite*. *Peeve* is a synonym for *annoyance*. As you noted, "*your favorite annoyance*" seems incongruous. And it is!

This is an example of irony:

> IRONY
>
> noun
>
> 1.the expression of one's meaning by using language that normally signifies the opposite, typically for humorous or emphatic effect

Pet Peeves tend to be *trivial, mundane* things that, for all intents and purposes, *should not annoy us*, but they do, and in ways we cannot explain without sounding *finicky* or *touchy*.

Comment: I've never come across the trivial meaning for 'epic' - is this specific to some regions?

Comment: It's not incongruous; there exists the idea of a phenomenon (which itself may exist or not, but that doesn't really matter) whereby a person dislikes some annoying thing X, but simultaneously enjoys being annoyed about X (enjoys complaining about it, for example). So a pet peeve may be one of a person's favorite things to complain about.

Comment: I think we're gonna need some citations for mundane sense of the word "epic".

Comment: Epic mundanity is part of the trend of superlatives getting overused. How often do people use the word "awesome" for something that is not awe-inspiring?

Comment: Great thread - http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26182/is-the-word-epic-being-used-correctly-these-days

Comment: @alcedine Care to leave that as an answer so I can vote it up? :)

Comment: A more accurate but less well-known example than _epic_ is _egregious_: it used to mean "outstanding" in a very positive sense (its Latin roots mean "out from the herd"; it meant "outstanding" even in ancient Rome); today it means "outstandingly bad". However, I think switching between opposites mainly happens with words for good and bad (it even happened to "bad" in 1970s slang). The meaning of "pet" in "pet peeve" is not the opposite of its primary meaning nor of an older meaning. The phrase simply makes an analogy: a source of annoyance cherished as one would a pet.

Comment: @BenKovitz: You know what really grinds my gears? Someone gave exactly what I want to know, but in the comment. (it's a long story why the explanation for *egregious* is important for me.)

Answer (score 13):

Poorly written advertising is my pet peeve. I lavish attention on it, point it out to my friends at every opportunity, and put a great deal of effort and care into its ridicule. I complain about it so much that you might think I enjoy it, just as I would enjoy playing with a beloved pet.

Comment: [Purrfect](http://www.purrfectfence.com) answer! Seriously, this should be the accepted answer. It explains the analogy exactly and succinctly.

Comment: So do you really enjoy it or not?

Answer (score 3):

The meaning of [***pet***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/pet) as used here is:

> 4) especially liked; favorite

So you could say:

> **favorite** peeve
>   **favorite** project

Answer (score 1):

Without etymology it's hard to be sure, but the phrase "pet hate" is common as well, as a synonym of "pet peeve".  In the UK I would say that "pet hate" is more common than "pet peeve", though not by as much as it used to be.  The simple "peeve" without "pet" is not very common as a noun, but is also seen, and again may be less common than it used to be.

Thus "pet peeve" could form by combining the synonyms "pet hate"+"peeve" for emphasis.

Interestingly [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pet) also gives:

> pet²  (pĕt) n. A fit of bad temper or pique.

I'm not for a moment claiming this to be a direct influence, but an indirect influence caused by a homonym for one component of the phrase having a similar meaning to the other may help it to become more common.

Comment: The phrase *pet peeve* is actually a bit of a pet hate of mine -- it seems tautological!

Comment: Hey I like your explanation.